# Django - Contain both register & login views on the same page

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am creating a simple application in Django, where my users can register and login to their accounts.

I have both a signup and a login form on my home page, but it doesn't work for logging in or registering: the form won't let the user's create an account or sign into their already existing account.

My Register Form:

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name = "email"  />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name = "username" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name = "password" />
                <button type = "submit" name = "register">Register</button>
            </form>
```

My login form:

```
<form  action = "" method = "POST">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name = "username" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name = "password"  />
                <button  type = "submit" name = "login">Log In</button>
                
            </form>
```

And finally, my view (I based it off [this]([How can i Register and Login In The Same Page in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71729572/how-can-i-register-and-login-in-the-same-page-in-django) solution but it doesn't work):

```
def home(request):
    if "register" in request.method == "POST":

        if request.method == "POST":
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            newuser = User.objects.create_user(username = username, email = email, password = password, )
            newuser.save()
        
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if "login" in request.method == "POST":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/levels/1") # redirect 2 dashboard
        else:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                password = request.POST.get('password')

                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)

                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/levels/1") #also redirect to dashboard
                else:
                    
                    print("error")


    
    return render(request, 'home.html', )
```

Can someone please help me? **I want it so I can have both a login and register form on the same screen**

I based my code off this: [How can i Register and Login In The Same Page in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71729572/how-can-i-register-and-login-in-the-same-page-in-django)

But it doesn't work

Comment: any errors? can u explain what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: please provide forms.py file related to this

Comment: I don't have a forms.py @ManojTolagekar

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but the login is not working and neither is the register: the user isn't getting logged in or registered when filling out the forms @HemalPatel

Comment: try `if "register" in request.POST` & `if "login" in request.POST` you did wrong condition check

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you try using different names for each inputs,  in your code you have used same names and i think its conflicting with each other!!!

Comment: I tried utilizing this approach but it did not work.

Comment: Can you please help good sir?

Comment: if that's not working, can you check your network by pressing f12, if its sending or receiving data!